# Find query by summing aggregated dictionary in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a db collection, users, that looks like this:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("4d2407265ff08824e3000001"), "karma": {"category1" : 5, "category2": 1, "category3": 7}} 
{"_id": ObjectId("4d2551b4ae9fa739640df821"), "karma": {"category1" : 1, "category3": 2, "category4": 3}} 
{"_id": ObjectId("4d255b115ff08821c2000001"), "karma": {"category2" : 6, "category3": 6, "category4": 6}}
```

I want to sum all karma values from the karma dict (total karma) and sort the result in descending order and limit to 2, so ideally I would get returned a list:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("4d255b115ff08821c2000001"), "totalKarma": 18} 
{"_id": ObjectId("4d2407265ff08824e3000001"), "totalKarma": 13}
```

Each karma dict does not necessarily contain the same keys.

Comment: To make this sort of thing easier, you may want to restructure your `karma` field to `[{category: "category1", value: 5}, {category: "category2", value: 1}, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use `mapReduce`. Here's a general idea:

First you'll have to write a map function which will emit values for `reduce` function to use:

```
var map = function(){
  /* emit values for each document */
  emit(key, value);
}
```

Second you'll have to write `reduce` function:

```
var reduce = function(key, value){
  //Here you'll sum all properties in 'karma' object
  var sum = 0;

  for(var karma in value){
    sum += parseInt(value[karma]);
  }

  return {"_id": key, "totalKarma": result};
}
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
db.users.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: "collectionToOutputTheResult" });
```

Or you can write all of the above in a `js` file & run it like this:

```
mongo localhost:27017/users script.js
```

[Here's](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) the documentation for `mapReduce`.